# Splitting up a large class with modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs

I'm attempting to build my first (browser) library, and chose to use the node-style commonjs modules + browserify to organize my code.  I've structured it so each module contains 1 class, which worked out pretty well until a few of the classes started getting eye-bleedingly huge.

So I let's say I have a class like

```
module.exports = MyClass;

function MyClass() {
  //initializing stuff

  this.publiceMethod= function publicMethod() {
    //do stuff
  };

  var privateMethod = function privateMethod() {
    //do stuff
  };
}

MyClass.prototype.notSureMethod = function notSureMethod() {
  //err... static method?
}
```

The problem is that I have a *large* amount of methods using various ways of declaring them ( `this.method`, `var method`, `this.prototype.method`).  What I'm wondering is if there is a relatively simple way to create another module(s) and require them into `MyClass` as part of the class definition in order to increase readability.

The ideal behavior that I'm looking for is something like a module that is a self-executing function that shares the same scope of what it's called from (including private variables / methods if possible).

I've only been learning JS for a few weeks now, so go easy on me if I'm being idiotic.  Thanks in advance :)

--edit--

Blindly playing around with it, I've figured out how to do what I'm looking for with prototype and public methods.

```
//Underneath MyClass definition
require('./prototype-methods')(MyClass);
require('./public-methods')(MyClass);
```

Then the gist of it in other files is:

```
module.exports = function(MyClass) {
  MyClass.prototype.method = . . . .

  MyClass.method = . . . .
}
```

So that leaves me wondering if there is a way to do something similar with private methods.  Any ideas?

---edit2---

> What exactly is you use case? Could you give an example of what your
>   class does?

I'm making a library for the web audio api that essentially lets you compose music.  I have a namespace for the library, and the namespace (at the moment) contains a few different classes.  There is the `score` class, which acts as a mediator between the `part`, `effect` and `player` classes.  The `part` class is just a wrapper for an `instrument`, which is an object with functions that play music.

The namespace has a factory function that returns a new instance of `score`, which in turn has a factory functions that return new `part`(s), `effect`(s), and eventually the `player`.  Also, there can be more than 1 score at any given time so I could potentially make a playlist.

I initially tried to use a purely functional pattern, but my code took on a new meaning of spaghetti.  I'm more familiar with namespacing / classes than I am functional patterns.  Overall, I've been building the library just as I would a normal javascript file, but due to the added complexity, have been using commonjs modules + browserify to easily split the code into different files / build the parts.

The specific class this question is about is the `part` class.  I'm wanting the library to be very flexible in what notations it accepts, so I needed to add quite a few methods to account for all of those notations (= big file).

Comment: Most of the time if you're using modules, you tend to refactor things to avoid using constructors unless necessary (well at least *I* do). BTW, how many lines is it?

Comment: At the moment, it's roughly 550 lines.  I'm not sure if that's considered to be large or small to others, but for me it is difficult to skim through it.  And thanks for the suggested edit - that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that I can pretty much add everything except for private members to `MyClass` with a module by passing `MyClass` to the module as a parameter.

It seems that I *could technically* add / access private members using `eval`, but I've been told it is evil.  Just taking the prototype and public methods out of the file trimmed it down significantly, so leaving the private members in there is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

isbn 978-0-596-80675-0 (Chapter 5 Object Creation Patterns / Sandbox Pattern),
isbn 0-596-10199-6 (Chapter 10 Modules and Namespaces / Module Utilities)

At the moment, I'm as well in search of convenient method of creating a privat data. I currently use a functional pattern of inheritance and defineClass like that:

```
var defineClass = function () {
    var inheritance = function inheritance() { };
    return function defineClass(data) {
        var classname = data.name,
            superclass = data.extend || Object,
            constructor = data.construct || function () { },
            methods = data.methods || {},
            statics = data.statics || {},
            borrows,
            provides;
        if (!data.borrows) {
            borrows = [];
        }
        else {
            if (data.borrows instanceof Array) {
                borrows = data.borrows;
            }
            else {
                borrows = [data.borrows];
            };
        };
        if (!data.provides) {
            provides = [];
        }
        else {
            if (data.provides instanceof Array) {
                provides = data.provides;
            }
            else {
                provides = [data.provides];
            };
        };
        inheritance.prototype = superclass.prototype;
        var proto = new inheritance();
        for (var i = 0; i < borrows.length; i++) {
            var c = borrows[i];
            for (var p in c.prototype) {
                if (typeof c.prototype[p] != "function") continue;
                proto[p] = c.prototype[p];
            }
        }
        for (var p in methods) {
            proto[p] = methods[p];
        };
        proto.constructor = constructor;
        constructor.superclass = superclass.prototype;
        if (classname) {
            proto.classname = classname;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < provides.length; i++) {
            var c = provides[i];
            for (var p in c.prototype) {
                if (typeof c.prototype[p] != "function") {
                    continue;
                };
                if (p == "constructor" || p == "superclass") {
                    continue;
                };
                if (p in proto && typeof proto[p] == "function" && proto[p].length == c.prototype[p].length) {
                    continue;
                };
                throw new Error("Class " + classname + " are not provided method " + c.classname + "." + p);
            };
        };
        constructor.prototype = proto;
        for (var p in statics) {
            constructor[p] = statics[p];
        };
        return constructor;
    }
}();

//SAMPLE CODE
var tempObj = function () { };
// example of a variable
tempObj.prototype.distance = 0;
// example of a method
tempObj.prototype.walk = function (time) {
    this.distance = this.distance + time * this.walkSpeed
};
tempObj.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.name + " distance " + this.distance
};

var Animal = defineClass({
    name: "Animal",
    construct: function (name, walkSpeed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.walkSpeed = walkSpeed;
    },
    borrows: tempObj,
    methods: {
        distance: tempObj.prototype.distance
    }
});

var tempObj2 = defineClass({
    methods: {
        fly: function (time) {
            this.distance = this.distance + time * this.flySpeed
        }
    }
});

var Bird = defineClass({
    name: "Bird",
    construct: function (name, walkSpeed, flySpeed) {
        // call the parent constructor
        Bird.superclass.constructor.call(this, name, walkSpeed)
        this.flySpeed = flySpeed
    },
    extend: Animal,
    borrows: tempObj2
});

var Cuckoo = defineClass({
    name: "Cuckoo",
    extend: Bird,
    construct: function (name, walkSpeed, flySpeed) {
        // call the parent constructor
        Cuckoo.superclass.constructor.call(this, name, walkSpeed, flySpeed)
        this.word = "cucoo";
    },
    methods: {
        say: function () {
            return this.name + " says " + this.word;
        }
    }
});

var animal = new Animal("Dog", 2);
animal.walk(3);
var dd = animal.toString();             // => Dog distance 6

bird = new Bird("Bird", 1, 10);
bird.walk(3);
var ww = bird.toString();               // => Bird distance 3
bird.fly(2);
var ff = bird.toString();               // => Bird distance 23

cuckoo = new Cuckoo("Cuckoo", 1, 10);
cuckoo.walk(3);
var ww = cuckoo.toString();             // => Cuckoo distance 3
cuckoo.fly(2);
var ff = cuckoo.toString();             // => Cuckoo distance 23
var cSay = cuckoo.say();                // => Cuckoo says cucoo
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is you use case? Could you give an example of what your class does?

Because going the object-oriented way is not alway the best way to do things in JavaScript. Node-style modules and the fact that functions are first-class citizens in js make it really easy to go the functional way. Meaning that you can export single functions which do exactly one thing. For example:

```
module.exports = function(x, y) {
  return x * y
}
```

And in a second module you can use this function like this:

```
var add = require('./add.js')
var result = add(15, 23);
```

If you want to learn more about this, check out [this nodeschool workshop](http://nodeschool.io/#functionaljs).

Comment: I updated my question to clarify my use case and class.